# UILongPressGestureRecognizer .minimumPressDuration not woking on iOS9

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, ios9, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have tried everything, and nothing seems to work, 
 
adding UILongPressGestureRecognizer in code with

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpOnView = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpOnView.minimumPressDuration = 1.0; //seconds
lpOnView.delegate = self;
[tblView addGestureRecognizer:lpOnView];
```

and the handle method looks like

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    NSLog(@"UILongPressGestureRecognizer");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"other gesture");
  }
  if ([self.tableView.gestureRecognizers containsObject:gestureRecognizer]){
    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

taping on tableView cells results in.

```
    2015-09-23 13:21:15.872 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:15.872 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
    2015-09-23 13:21:15.930 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:15.931 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.354 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.354 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.398 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.398 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.398 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.399 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.410 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:19.411 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.104 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.105 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.161 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.162 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.710 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.711 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.750 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.750 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.751 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.751 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.762 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    2015-09-23 13:21:20.763 SV[407:74584] UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
    2015-09-23 13:21:21.240 SV[407:74584] UILongPressGestureRecognizer
```

why does Tap execute this event, it should wait at least a second to execute ? 
 
THIS started happening on iOS9, on iOS8 works OK.

Comment: The touch happens as soon as it happens. You are not testing the case for ...Reconized. That's the one that will tell you when the press is over the timer (I believe). A long press is a single time event. Not like Pan which is an ongoing event.

Comment: The UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, so checking for one is like checking for other, it has the same Enum value and Switch command does not allow to have two of the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering my own question, this is to help anyone that has the same problem. 
 Updating Infragistics Nuclios 2014 vol. 1 to vol. 2 solved the issue. So it was not a problem with iOS9, but with a third party Framework.